# Getting started with express

Tags: node.js, express

I am just getting started learning node.js and express, so forgive me if my question uses the wrong terminology. Hey, gotta start somewhere I guess. So I am following an online tutorial and it aint doing what its supposed to do. (I've got soapui and postman installed, also just learning the ropes) So to the code:

```html
// Defined store route
gameRoutes.route('/add').post(function(req, res) {

  let game = new Game(req.body);

  game.save()

    .then(game => {
      res.status(200).json({
        'game': 'CoGamein added successfully'
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});
```

Tried using the insert code widget but failed miserably, sorry! Anyway what's happening is the data is added to the database but the res.status(200).json({'game': 'CoGamein added successfully'}); is not firing,  and VScode gives me a vague error that let game = new Game(req.body); data is not read! Any ideas whats going on?

```html
// Game.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Define collection and schema for Games
let Game = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  price: {
    type: Number
  }
},{
    collection: 'games'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', Game);
```

Comment: Can you post the code inside your Game constructor

Comment: The error occurs inside the Game constructor, so please post it.

Comment: // Game.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Define collection and schema for Games
let Game = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  price: {
    type: Number
  }
},{
    collection: 'games'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', Game);

Comment: Do you get the 400 error?

Comment: Actually, where do you get the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gameRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {

    let game = new Game(req.body);

    game.save()
        .then(game => {
            res.send({
                game: 'CoGamein added successfully'
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
        });
});
```

`200` is the default success status. You don't need to mention that.

Comment: Nope, same deal, data is inserted but no message is shown in nodemon server terminal. Thanks for trying though..

Comment: This code will not show the response in terminal. It will send the response to the consumer of the API. To get the message in terminal you have to log the object separately by adding `console.log({
                game: 'CoGamein added successfully'
            })` before `res.send`